# Molecular Orbital Diagram

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure

Chemists have revealed that $1 \lambda^{2}, 2 \lambda^{2}$ -disilene $\left(\mathrm{Si}_{2}\right)$ is diamagnetic while disulfur $\left(\mathrm{S}_{2}\right)$ is paramagnetic $(\mathrm{S}=1)$. Draw the MO diagram (valence shell only), determine the bond order for those two molecules and conjecture which element has higher $3 \mathrm{~s}-3 \mathrm{p}$ energy gap.
(Note that $\sigma_{\mathrm{g} 3 \mathrm{pz}}$ is lower-lying than $\pi_{\mathrm{u} 3 \mathrm{p}}$ in $\mathrm{S}_{2} .$ )

It seems that the paramagnetic type is not very necessary - however, I couldn't come up with the correct MO diagram in either case.

Comment: use the easy to find diagrams for C2 and O2 as guides

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. In short: It would be a good idea to post whatever you have come up with so far.

Comment: Related: [Why is diboron (B2) paramagnetic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14676/4945)

Comment: @Andrew Would the diagrams of $C_2$ and $O_2$ be sufficient to draw the original molecular orbital diagrams? Could you please elaborate more about what you mentioned, still can not figure out the relation between it and the given problem.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン How diboron's being paramagnetic such related to the stated problem?! The original question asks to draw the MO diagrams with valence shell only. I would be pleased if you could provide more insights about the proposed problem specifically.

Comment: Can anyone suggest concrete ideas on how this question could be solved more rigorously in terms of formal diagrams?

Comment: The answer I have given in the question I have previously linked gives you generic MO diagrams for diatomic molecules with and without mixing. These should at least provide enough guidance to add the requirements to this question according to the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/). Please [edit] the question to include you thoughts towards the solution of the exercise. And while you are at it, please add a citation for the original source of the exercise.